# A Quadratic diophantine equation

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

How to prove or disprove this statement:

For all $c<z<0<s$, there exists $0<k\leq i$, $0\leq j<s+i$, such that all conditions hold simultaneously:

1. $z=is+i(i-1)/2-j-k(s+i+2j)-k(k-1)/2$,
2. $z<c+s+i+2j+k+1$ and $0<is+i(i-1)/2-j-(k-1)(s+i+2j)-(k-1)(k-2)/2$
3. for all $0\leq m<i$ and $0<n<k$, a) holds

a) $ms+m(m-1)/2\neq is+i(i-1)/2-j-n(s+i+2j)-n(n-1)/2$

All variables are integers. I have tried computationally to find a counterexample but without luck.

---

This would imply the existence of several [Self-avoiding walk on $\mathbb{Z}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/111377/self-avoiding-walk-on-mathbbz) . (but not the converse.)

Comment: Seems like an extremely uninteresting question, which no one would ever want to think about. Maybe if we knew how you stumbled upon all those formulas, we'd find it worth a thought.

Comment: I sort of appreciate the quirky humor involved in the current title, but I also think that I have a strange sense of humor.

Comment: It's basically the same algorithm as in my answer here, but in 1 dimension: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/88659/traversing-the-infinite-square-grid

Comment: Every unintresting question is intresting to somebody who was looking for unintresting questions.

Comment: This might be a silly question, but are automatic theorem provers anywhere close to proving statements like these?

Comment: @mmm: please stop with these ridiculous edits. You are needlessly bumping this question up to the front page, and those edits can be seen as vandalism.

Comment: Since the "Self-avoiding walk" problem (the motivation for the OP) has been solved on mathoverflow without any ugly equations, I think we may safely declare this question completely unintereseting.